# Equivalent to !== null and === null in Java

Tags: javascript, java

I stumbled upon a Javascript code for the comparison symbol === and !== that I'm not familiar with in Java:

```
  if ((arc === null) || (arc.width > width)) {
                        arc = { circle : circle,
                                width : width,
                                p1 : p1,
                                p2 : p2};
                    }
 if (arc !== null) {
                arcs.push(arc);
                arcArea += circleArea(arc.circle.radius, arc.width);
                p2 = p1;
            }
```

From Googling it "===" means equal value and equal type while "!==" means not equal value or not equal type. So I tried to translate it to Java code like this:

```
if (arc.equals(null) || (arc.width > width)) {
                            arc.circle = circle;
                            arc.width = width;
                            arc.p1 = p1;
                            arc.p2 = p2;
                        }
if (!arc.equals(null)) {
                    arcs.add(arc);
                    arcArea += circleArea(arc.circle.radius, arc.width);
                    p2 = p1;
                }
```

But it gave me the wrong result in the end as the second if is not executed somehow. Is my code correct? What is the equivalent code for the aforementioned symbols in Java?

Comment: Just do `arc == null` and `arc != null`. You can't compare different types anyway in java. Also, what's the point of comparing + type check if you're comparing to `null`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I did that as well but the second if is never executed not sure why

Comment: Looks like `arc` is always `null`. In which case the whole thing should explode (with a `NullPointerException`). Give a bit more context around that piece of code, because it's not making sense otherwise.

Comment: Just guessing: this is inside a `try-catch`, `arc` is `null`, you do `arc.circle = circle`, the exception is catched and you jump right after this piece of code

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Not sure wether the downvote on the (deleted) answer is right. Poster did fullfill OP's requirements and linked the source, even without the quotation marks

Comment: @Logar did I downvote? I just pointed it out.

Comment: I don't know, I saw a downvote right after your comment, but sorry if I guessed bad

Comment: @Logar anyway the post has been deleted by the owner, they'll get their points back anyway :) Also, I see why you may think I downvoted. it went from +3 to +2 because I removed my *upvote* after noticing it was a copy.